# Webanalytics beacons

Tags: javascript, web, analytics

I'm wondering why web analytics softwares use a 1x1 gif element to send a beacon, rather than simply including a

`<script src='http://my.analytics.com/script.js?my=params'></script>`

element to send the beacon and thus avoid having to actually return a 1x1 pixel gif, since an empty response would be a valid javascript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One the reasons might be that a .gif will be loaded even by users that don't have javascript activated.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely to cater for javascript disabled scenarios.